# model.ecore is not generated project\target\classes\package\gen\model\impl during maven 'clean install' goal

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-emf

I'm trying to create a Maven emf project, which can be packaged into a standalone jar, so that other projects can use it.

What I have did so far.

- Created a Maven project and created the ECore model and created it's genModel file.
- Now, I would like to package this project into a jar, so, that other projects can work on it.
- When I run the goal 'clean install' the jar file is being created.
- when I add this artifact as dependency and try to access any model object, it get the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: model.ecore
at model.impl.ModelPackageImpl.loadPackage(TSGPackageImpl.java:13231) ~[sample.model-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at model.impl.ModelPackageImpl.init(ModelPackageImpl.java:2792) ~[sample.model-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at model.ModelPackage.<clinit>(ModelPackage.java:60) ~[sample.model-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

While searching for that specific issue, I understood that the model.ecore file should be present under the model.impl package, from below links:

- [Missing serialized package: uml.ecore](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201826/)
- [XSD to EMF Cannot Find *ecore File](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/22408/)
- [java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: TestSchema.ecore](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/131171/)

-> Whenever the 'clean install' goal is run in maven, the folder 'project\target\classes' is fully cleaned and the class files are generated. But, I could not find the model.ecore file in the 'project\target\classes\package\gen\model\impl' folder. is there a specific way I can generate so that mode.ecore, after cleaning?

-> When I try 'project-> clean project' in eclipse, then, the 'project\target\classes' is fully cleaned and the class files along with mode.ecore files are generated.

-> is some EMF builder is not run during the 'clean install' goal?

-> Could someone point a way to generate the model.ecore file, during 'clean install' goal?

The project's pom.xml

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<artifactId>sample.model</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Emf dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.edit</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you have different versions of org.eclipse.emf? I would assume thy should be the same?

Comment: No good reason, but, from the Maven central repo, only these close versions of emf jars where present, so, I have taken them. Can changing the emf jars' version can fix it?

Comment: Maybe if there have been changes in the internal structure.... ?

Comment: But, locally, when I build with in Eclipse workspace (rather than maven goal), the model.ecore file is present, with the same emf dependencies. Should I added another other dependecy for the EMF builder to kick in and add that .ecore file?